# Where do you store/create your model in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at some sample apps build with Angular. I am looking where the models are created / stored. I've noticed that sometimes the model is stored in a plain javascript file, like this:

customer.js:

```
function customer(){
  this.firstName;
  this.lastName;
}

customer.prototype.getFullName = function(){
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
}
```

And what I also see is the use of a factory:

customerFactory.js:

```
app.factory("customer", function(){
  return function(){
    this.firstName;
    this.lastName;

    this.getFullName = function(){
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    };
  };
});
```

So my question is, where do you store your model and why? Does the one has more advantages than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I particularly prefer the second approach, that is, use a factory to create the models.

```
myApp.factory('Models', [function() {
    return {
        Customer: (function() {
            var cls = function(obj) {
                this.firstName = obj && obj.firstName || null;
                this.lastName = obj && obj.lastName || null;
            }
            cls.prototype.getFullName = function() {
                return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
            };
            return cls;
        })(),
        Order: (function() {
            var cls = function(obj) {
                this.id = obj.id || null;
                this.amount = obj.amount || null;
            }
            /* methods */
            return cls;
        })()
    }
}]);
```

This way, you only has to inject a single dependency in your controllers and it become explicity that the object is a defined model.

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Model', function($scope, Model) {
    $scope.customer = new Model.Customer({
        firstName: "Beterraba"
        , lastName: "Abacate"
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, just out of curiosity: 1) What does 'cls' stand for. 2)Why does the Customer object invokes itself? 3) Do you place all your models in the same factory?

Comment: @Martijn (1) "cls" stands for "class", that is a reserved word in js. (2) The object invokes itself so it only evaluate his body once. If it was a normal function, every `new` call would evaluate the entire class  again. (3) I like to put everything in a single factory to avoid several injections in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create a folder called `models` and each model gets its own file, defined as a factory.  I also use `$resource` to define my models, so that I never need to worry about `$http` calls (well, almost never).

Why?  Because this is the way that Angular apps are built.  Doing so allows you to inject them into your controllers, directives, etc.  If you prefer to have your models be Angular agnostic, that is fine.  It fits with the "Ports and Adapters" architecture.  Just expose them as a factory later.  Separate your Angular-agnostic code into a separate library, and then just expose them for injection later:

```
app.factory("Customer", function(){ return Models.Customer; });
app.factory("Order", function(){ return Models.Order; });
```

Also, notice that I like to name my class objects with capitals... it is a convention I really like to indicate that it is a "class" to be instantiated.

Comment: Thanks, so in your case there are two ways of defining a model: one in a file and one using a resource? With Angular agnostic, you mean unaware of Angular? So just plain javascript?

Comment: Right.  Personally, I prefer to just put it all in a service.  Some people, however, like the "ports and adapters" style of architecture that says your model/buisiness logic/utilty code is just pure JavaScript and knows nothing about Angular.  Then, you just wire it up like above.  In that example, Model.Customer is just pure JavaScript and doesn't live within the confines of Angular, but it is "adapted" using a `factory`.